# OpenSSL SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE never recovers during SSL_write()

Tags: ssl, openssl, client-server

I have two applications talking to each other over SSL.  The client is running on a windows machine, the server is a linux based application.  The client is sending a large amount of data to the server on startup.  The data is sent in ~4000byte chunks over to the server that contains 30 entries.  I have to send about 50000 entries over.

During that transmission the server sends a message to the client, the message size is ~4000bytes.  After that happens, the SSL_write() on the client side begins to return error of SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE.  The client sleeps for 10ms, and retries the SSL_write with the exact same parameters, however, the SSL_write fails infinitely.  Subsequently it aborts.  If it tries to send a new message, I get an error indicating I am not sending the same aborted message from earlier.

error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING: bad write retry”

The server eventually kills the connection since it has not heard from the client for 60s and re-establishes a new one.  This is just an FYI, the real issue is how can I get SSL_write to resume.

If the server does not send a request during the receive the problem goes away.  If I shrink the size of the request from 16K to 100 bytes the problem does not happen.

The SSL CTX MODE is set to SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY and SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER.

Does anyone have an idea what might cause a simultaneous transmission from both sides with large information can cause this failure.  What can I do to prevent it if this is a limitation other than capping the size that goes out from the server to the client.  My concern is that if the client is not sending anything the throttling I applied to avoid this issue is a waste.

On the client side I tried to perform an SSL_read to see if I need to read during a write even though I never receive an SSL_ERROR_PENDING_READ, but the buffer is not that big anyway.  ~1000bytes in size.

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I had one more thought, could it be that the Windows client is consumed with sending its message but the buffer is full because the server is busy sending its own message to the client and not draining the rx buffer.  Essentially a deadlock scenario!

Answer (score 6):

SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE - This error is returned by OpenSSL (I am assuming you are using OpenSSL) only when socket send gives it an EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN error. The socket send will give a EWOUDLBLOCK error when the send side buffer is full, which in turn means that your Server is not reading the messages sent from Client.

So, essentially, the problem lies with your Server which is not reading the messages sent to it. You need to check your server and fix it, which will automatically fix your client problem.

Also, why have you set the option "SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER"? SSL always expects that the record which it is trying to send should be sent completely before the next record can be sent.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out that with both the client and server side app, the read and writes are processed in one thread.  In a perfect storm as I described above, the client is busy writing (non blocking).  The server then decides to do a write a large set of messages of its own in between processing its rx buffers.  The server tx is a blocking call.  The server gets stuck writing, starves the read, the buffers fill up and we have a deadlock scenario.

The default windows buffer is 8k bytes so it doesn't take much to fill it up.

The architecture should be such that there is a separate thread for the rx and tx processing on both sides.  As a short cut/term fix, once can increase the rx buffers and rate limit the tx side to prevent the deadlock.